# Linking URL for whatsapp business when both whatsapp and whatsapp business applications are installed

Tags: deep-linking, whatsapp, deeplink, react-native-deep-linking

I know that we can use following url to open whatsapp from my react native application

```
whatsapp://send?text=MyTextMessage&phone=MyPhoneNumber
```

Or we can use

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=MyPhoneNumber&text=MyTextMessage
```

This works fine when i have only installed a whatsapp application.
Now along with whatsapp i have also installed WhatsApp Business application as well.
But since after i installed whatsapp business as well my above code gives me option to make a choice between whatsapp or whatsapp business to open.

**I don;t want choice rather from my application i want to open chat for phone number in url in either whatsapp or whatsapp business directly based on users selection.**

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: My phone doesnt even give me a choice. How to get it to atleast give a choice